# Django Ajax Post Request by Using Checkbox in CBV

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, ajax

I'm trying to send ajax post requests to my server to add or remove objects by using just checkboxes (not form). Here is a screenshot of what I got visually:

https://pasteboard.co/IMHHSa6.png

When I click any of the checkboxes I got http500 (internal server error) as response. In cmd I see the error that says there is no matching query: **app1.models.Influencer.DoesNotExist: Influencer matching query does not exist.**

The thing is I'm pretty sure that the object with that id exists in the database. I spend much time inspecting Django's CSRF documentation and watching youtube videos about django-ajax examples. Here is my code:

**views.py**:

```
class InfluencerListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Influencer
    context_object_name = 'influencers' # not necessary, default is object_list

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        inf_id = request.POST.get('inf.id')
        list_id = request.POST.get('list.id')
        i = Influencer.objects.get(id=inf_id)
        l = InfluencerList.objects.get(id=list_id)
        l.influencers.add(i)
        data = {
                'result' : 'some result'
        }
        return JsonResponse(data)     

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        logged_in_user = self.request.user
        context['myLists'] = logged_in_user.lists.annotate(influencers_count=Count('influencers'))
        return context
```

**models.py:**

```
class Influencer(models.Model):
    # fields are not included for the sake of clarity

class InfluencerList(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Name:', max_length=20, blank=False)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='lists')
    influencers = models.ManyToManyField('Influencer', related_name='lists')
```

**scripts.js**

```
function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = cookies[i].trim();
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}

function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}

function myFunc(_self) {
    inf_id = _self.getAttribute('data-inf_id');
    list_id = _self.getAttribute('data-list_id');
    console.log(inf_id + " " + list_id); # I CAN SEE THOSE  IDS IN CONSOLE AND THEY EXIST IN DB
    var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
    if(_self.checked == true){
        console.log("checked!");

        $.ajaxSetup({
            beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
                if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
                }
            }
        });

        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/influencers',
            data: {
                'inf_id': inf_id,
                'list_id': list_id,
                'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrftoken
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                console.log("succes!");
            }
        });
    }
    else{
         console.log("unchecked!");       
    }
}
```

I also added this line somewhere in my view file (where I put it doesn't matter as long as it's in the body since I'm not using any forms. Please correct me if I'm wrong):

```
<input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='{{ csrf_token }}' />
```

Comment: Isn't this `request.POST.get('inf_id')` instead of `request.POST.get('inf.id')`?

Comment: @Willem I must get some sleep i think... Thanks again :)